# iptables error with No such file or directory

Tags: iptables

I have CentOS 6 x86_64 vps server. I just created the following iptables. But it gives an error message. What am I doing wrong here?

```
*filter
:INPUT    DROP    [0:0]
:FORWARD  DROP    [0:0]
:OUTPUT   ACCEPT  [0:0]
:SERVICE  -       [0:0]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 4  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j SERVICES
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A SERVICES -p tcp --dport 61203 -j ACCEPT
-A SERVICES -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A SERVICES -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

# service iptables start
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.7: Couldn't load target `SERVICES':/lib64/xtables/libipt_SERVICES.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Error occurred at line: 9
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
:SERVICE  -       [0:0]
...
-A SERVICES -p tcp --dport 61203 -j ACCEPT
-A SERVICES -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A SERVICES -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Notice the issue?

:)

Hint: (mouseover)

> You have a singular/plural mismatch.

Comment: so what is the correct way?? Is it SERVICES - [0:0]

Comment: You defined a chain. When you reference that chain, you need to use the correct name.